# Using external callback function data inside vuejs component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jszip

Hello and Happy holidays !!

I need advice on how I could get data from an external function that generate a zipfile into my vuejs component, to create a progress bar for JSZip plugin: https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip/generate_async.html

I import my file :
**import { generateZIP } from "@/utils/downloader.js";**

and call it inside vuejs from a method trigger by a button:

```
<template>
...
<div v-for="result of results" :key="result.item.refID">
        <section class="row" @click="selectByRow(result.item)">
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            :id="result.item.refID"
            :value="result.item.refID"
            v-model="checkedItems"
            class="checkbox"
          />
          </div>
          <!-- FOUND RESULTS -->
          <div class="name">{{ result.item.marketingName }}</div>
        </section>
      </div>
      <!-- Download all checked items -->

      <div>
        <button
          v-if="checkedItems.length > 1"
          @click="downloadAll(checkedItems)"
          class="button"
        >
          Download Selection
        </button>
</template>
...
<script>
import { mapState, mapActions, mapMutations, mapGetters } from "vuex";
import { generateZIP } from "@/utils/downloader.js";
...

export default {
data() {
    return {
      // Path to point to pictures storage
      domainName: this.$domainName,
      // Array to gather search results
      searchArray: [],
      checkedItems: [],
      // make a special array for row selection
      checkedRow: []
    };
  },
  methods: 
     downloadAll(files) {
      // Prepare path
      const fullPath = `${this.domainName}/files/${this.reqPath}/`;

      const filesArray = [];
      files.forEach(fileID => {
        let obj = this.results.find(value => value.item.refID == fileID);
        if (obj.item.images !== undefined) {
          filesArray.push(obj.item.images);
        }
      });
      generateZIP(filesArray.flat(), fullPath);
    },
 selectByRow(resultID) {
      // Check if select resultID.refID is already in checkedItems and store it in variable if its present.
      const isInArray = this.checkedItems.find(name => name === resultID.refID);
      // if the ref not in array, add it
      if (!isInArray) {
        this.checkedItems.push(resultID.refID);
        // Add checkedRow full information object
        this.checkedRow.push(resultID);
      } else {
        // if already in array, remove it
        this.checkedItems = this.checkedItems.filter(
          name => name !== resultID.refID
        );

        this.checkedRow = this.checkedRow.filter(
          name => name.refID !== resultID.refID
        );
      }
...
```

Everything working, now I add some feedback showing the zip progress. There is an available callback function "updateCallback" that I'll call in my downloader.js

```
zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"}, function updateCallback(metadata) {
    console.log("progression: " + metadata.percent.toFixed(2) + " %");
    if(metadata.currentFile) {
        console.log("current file = " + metadata.currentFile);
    }
})
...
export {
  generateZIP
}
```

Cool it displays progression in my console log.

But HOW could I import this metadata object into vue to display it in my app ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Can you add some more information about the (Vue) code you already have?

Comment: I added the full method code, the vuefile is quite big i don't want to pollute. The "files" array is a list of objects corresponding to picture urls, their names and relativepath. I download those picture from my downloader and gather them in a zip.

Comment: You could strip down the code so it contains only the parts that are relevant for your problem, see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Use data properties in your vue component. 
Inside the callback, link your instance (this) to local var, to pass value between callback data and reactive property. For example: let var=this

Comment: sorry but how do i important it into my vue component ?? (i checked the reactive property doc but i don't get it... they use Vue.set or this.$set but i don't understand how I can apply this with my case